# Recover the syntactic sugar of operators

Tags: r, metaprogramming

Is it possible to reapply syntactic sugar to expressions that contain operators? I am looking for a function `f()` that works as follows:

```
f(quote(`+`(x_1, x_2, x_3, 2) - 1))
#> x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 2 - 1

f(quote(`-`(1, `*`(2, 3, 4))))
#> 1 - 2 * 3 * 4

f(quote(c(`+`(1, 2), `+`(10, 11))))
#> c(1 + 2, 10 + 11)

f(quote(c(1, 2)))
#> c(1, 2)
```

Motivation: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/792#issuecomment-475482060

Comment: Does `f()` just print or does it return an object?

Comment: I would like `f()` to accept an expression and return an expression. If possible, I would like to avoid parsing and deparsing because those operations are slow.

Comment: `\`+\`(x_1, x_2, x_3, 2)` has a different abstract syntax tree than `x_1 +  x_2 + x_3 + 2` so they aren't really the same thing to R. In fact `\`+\`(5,6,7)` returns an error because `+` only expects two parameters. Note that `quote(c(\`+\`(1, 2), \`+\`(10, 11)))` already returns the expression in the "normalized" form.

Comment: And the proper transformation for is `x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 2 - 1` is `quote(\`+\`(\`+\`(\`+\`(x_1, x_2), x_3),2)-1)`. You'll notice the latter is automatically formatted as you would expect. As long as you have the correct equivalent expressions, you'll get the results you desired. Right now, your expressions just aren't equivalent.

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense. Seems now like `\`+\`(too, many, args)` in an unavoidable edge case. For what I am trying to do, I do not think it makes sense to go back, detect `+` statically, and then convert to `\`+\`(\`+\`(too, many), args)`.